# Best (performant) way to handle event tracking in web apps

Tags: javascript, tracking, progressive-enhancement, progressive-web-apps

**Current Scenario**

In one of our SPA web app, we are tracking various user actions like `cta clicks`, `page navigations` etc using our custom tracker request which passes some information to the backend using POST request.

**Problem**
Now because these tracking request our instant (though in async manner but running on same thread), these requests will be fighting against any other events happening on the same page thread.

**Desired effect**
Ideally, if these tracking data could be collected & a single request be sent at a fix interval of time (maybe every minute), that would hugely improve, both the client side performance & will also reduce the load on server where tracking request is sent.

**Solutions**

- Using Localstorage - One immediate solution that came to my mind was to use the LocalStorage to keep the tracking data which will be preserved even if user leaves the page immediately before the call is fired. But the problem is that, due to  `x seconds` timeout, if the user closes the tab & never comes back, the data will be in the localStorage but it will never be sent.

Are there any proper solutions out there that could help in achieving this desired effect? Maybe `backgroundSync` API?

Comment: Please provide what evidence you have that this is actually impacting client-side performance.

Comment: I feel like the only event that could get you into trouble would be if you tracked mouse movement. Clicks and page views are so few and in between, if you have client side or server side issues, you have some other problem.

Comment: There are trackers which even track mouse movements, and as long as you debounce them a bit even that does not cause a problem.

Comment: Are you really concerned about losing a few seconds of data from the final session of the user's life?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sort of wondering if you really need to solve this problem, but here's an [example of offline analytics](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/ioweb2015/blob/master/app/scripts/shed/offline-analytics.js) that might help.

There's not much information on [Background Sync](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync) (available since Chrome M49) but [this introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync?hl=en) is a starting point.